# Drawing an analogy from SQL/Relational Algebra to *nix command-line filters/tools

Tags: sql, linux, join, awk, relational-algebra

Tools like `cat/tac`, `grep/sed`, `head/tail`, `cut`,`sort/uniq`, `comm` and `join` make it easy - when chained together - to extract data from one or multiple files.
The dominating paradigm in this context is that of creating a "pipeline" or applying "filters" to extract information.

I was thinking that a different perspective, that of Relational Operators, may be useful when applied to text files,
at least as a conceptual framework which may help me better utilize and combine these tools to extract and transform data.

My question is:  Could someone suggest me some examples showing an analogy between relational operators/SQL queries and Unix filtering pipelines?

To make it more specific and potentially more useful, I provide here two tabular white space-separated datasets created with [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/),
containing numerical, nominal and ordinal values:

```
$ cat so_tag_rank.txt
Tag           Group      MayRank   TotalRank  QuestionsInMay  QuestionsTotal
javascript    Lang       1         2          25111           869428
java          Lang       2         1          21331           870935
android       Platform   3         5          17351           682459
php           Lang       4         4          16910           761350
c#            Lang       5         3          15296           805666
jquery        Library    6         6          12950           621883
python        Lang       7         7          12394           434282
html          Markup     8         8          11672           422871
ios           Platform   9         10         9465            340714
css           Style      10        12         8141            310651


$ cat so_upvote_ratio.txt
Tags          Group       Upvotes    Downvotes    UD_ratio
c#            Lang        3692949    110750       3
java          Lang        3643245    112450       3.09
javascript    Lang        3326801    122302       3.68
c++           Lang        2247424    71309        3.17
python        Lang        2227963    59990        2.69
php           Lang        2177780    106569       4.89
android       Platform    2094791    59973        2.86
jquery        Library     2054170    68602        3.34
html          Markup      1444111    67129        4.65
.net          Platform    1334296    38208        2.86
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's specify that we don't care about *named* columns (you may ignore headers and specify columns positionally - Symbolic names can be simulated using variables in a shell script).

I would be interested in oneliners/scripts using one or more of the commands: `cat/tac`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `head/tail`, `cut`, `sort`, `uniq`, `comm`, `diff`, `join`, `rev`, `tee`, `paste` in a sh/bash shell, simulating some of the following SQL commands/Relational operations:

**Selection, Projection, Union**

```
  SELECT [DISTINCT] select_expr [FROM file_refs]  
    [WHERE where_condition] | [WHERE_IN strlist]  
    [GROUP BY {col | expr}]  
    [HAVING where_condition]  
    [ORDER BY {col | expr} [ASC | DESC]]  
    [LIMIT {num_rows OFFSET offset}]  
    UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...(sub-query)..
```

**Joins/Products**:

```
  [LEFT | RIGHT] [INNER | OUTER] JOIN [ON {on_expression} | USING {using_expression}]
```

**Functions and comparison**

```
Aggregation   : CONCAT, COUNT, SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG, MEDIAN, MODE, INDEXOF_MAX, INDEXOF_MIN  
Comparison    : =,>,<, LIKE/NOT LIKE, NULL/NOT NULL, IN/NOT IN, Dates comparison
Boolean operators : AND,OR,NOT,XOR
```

**Advanced operations**

```
Band/Range JOIN, Self JOIN  
Views (Temporary files?), Difference/Except, Division  
Sub-queries/Nested queries  
Contingency tables
```

I would prefer creativity over portability in this case.

Comment: I typically go the other way.  When I want to run SQL queries on data, I load it into a DB where I can use SQL natively.  For example, Postgresql has VALUE tables and some native type coercion which I like to abuse for small data sets like this.  I like your idea but it seems like you'd need a code framework to present a *nix system as an SQL implementor.  How would you expect to identify types:  boolean, dates, strings, numbers, NULL in files?  For example, booleans in random files might be identified as "true", "t", "F", 0, 1 etc...

Comment: You're right that _type safety_ is not something you can depend on when using free-text manipulation tools like those. I use `R` when I want to declare data 
types and perform more sophisticated analysis. However, most of the times, during interactive terminal work you want quick results without 
the overhead of migrating your data to DBs or using full-blown programming lang. Also they use a tiny (usually constant) amount of memory, compared 
to other tools like `R` which need to load the whole file in memory, unpractical for large files.

Comment: What I am interested more in this context is the conceptual connection of slicing vertically (`awk/cut`), horizontally (`grep/sed/head/tail`) and across files (`cat/join/comm` etc.) with Relational and Set operations like projection/selection/union/intersection etc. 
as a means to obtain a more systematic way of thinking on how to use these tools.

Comment: Googling: [Relational shell programming](http://matt.might.net/articles/sql-in-the-shell/), [The UNIX Shell As a Fourth Generation Language](https://www.gnu.org/software//nosql/4gl.txt), [RDB -- A UNIX Command-Line Database](http://www.drdobbs.com/rdb-a-unix-command-line-database/199101326) .Re nature & benefits of pure relational notation & semantics vs (perhaps a requirement of yours) SQL see Hugh Darwen's free online book An Introduction to Relational Database Theory and its companion SQL: A Comparative Survey.

Comment: @philipxy Thank you for the links. I had found the first one myself but I think the presented examples and the provided solutions are quite naive. The `/rdb` links are indeed quite useful since they provide the conceptual framework I was referring to. It is unfortunate though that they dictate the usage of a specific data format and talk about specially implemented tools, when there are other unix tools which can do the same job. However, I will use the provided examples and commands and try to emulate them with common unix utils. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The relational model was conceived as a ***general-purpose*** data management tool.  As such, it is capable and powerful enough to express, basically, everything and anything.

As a consequence, the kind of stuff that is expressible/doable in *ix pipeline commands is a proper subset of what is expressible/doable in RA.  (But note that RA requires the stuff you're working on to have a declared relational structure, which the output of *ix commands do not.)

For example, a FIND filter (sorry for this ancient DOS example) is somewhat akin to WHERE X LIKE '%myfind%', clearly a restriction.

For example, the fact of pipelining itself is somewhat akin to relational operator nesting.

But to be honest, most of the operations supported by RA do not seem to have a more or less direct counterpart in the commands set.

Comment: The analogy of pipelining with relational operator nesting is a useful concept, thanks

Comment: So, could you give me an example of a RA operation not feasible with one of the listed tools? Having included `awk`, a turing-complete language, I suppose that the opposite is true, SQL and Relational Algebra can do only a subset of what `awk` can do, they are just more _expressive_  for the task they are created for.

Comment: Relational projection that doesn't preserve any key of the input (I mean with the consequence that duplicate elimination is to be performed) seems like a good candidate.  Aggregations and transitive closures probably are too, but those are typically not first-class citizens in any RA course.

Comment: Relational projection (either with duplicate elimination or not) can be easily performed with `awk` in one line. Aggregations too. Of course transitive closures will require more coding.

Comment: I don't know ix shell stuff well enough, and I most certainly don't know *anything* about awk, but a cursory inspection of what it is about leads me to think that it will involve quite a lot of "programming" before you can get awk to produce "behaviour" that is comparable to RA operators.  iow awk offers a "sub-language" in which its users can do their programming.  The more powerful that language, the more likely it is that you can get all of the RA operators implemented in it.  Question remains whether that really is the same kind of equivalence as pipelining/nesting.